# GetLegendGraphic in GeoServer won't apply style based on language

Tags: geoserver, wms, internationalization, getlegendgraphic

Having trouble with i18n in SLD styles in a GetLegendGraphic call, using GeoServer 2.21.4. In the following style the first rule will always get picked up, regardless of any language parameter in the URL. Adding a `rule=demostyle_sv` will use the Swedish version instead. In addition, the `${language()}` substitution goes through unchanged which points at that function being unavailable at this point or in some way limited as to which attributes it will work in.

Is this styling solution even supposed to work, and if so, how?

The call is as follows:
https://REDACTED/geoserver/XXXX/wms?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetLegendGraphic&Language=sv&style=TEST_STYLE&format=image%2Fpng&width=200&height=200&layer=A_LAYER

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>layer_name</Name>
<UserStyle>
  <Name>Demo style</Name>
    <Title>Demo style
      <Localized lang="fi">Demotyyli</Localized>
      <Localized lang="sv">Demostil</Localized>
    </Title>
  <FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
      <Name>demostyle_fi</Name>
       <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:Function name="language"/>
          <ogc:Literal>fi</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <RasterSymbolizer>
          <ColorMap  type="values">
            <ColorMapEntry label="Suomeksi: ${language()}" color="#006100" quantity="1" />            
          </ColorMap>
      </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>demostyle_sv</Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:Function name="language"/>
          <ogc:Literal>sv</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <RasterSymbolizer>
          <ColorMap  type="values">
            <ColorMapEntry label="På svenska: ${language()}" color="#006100" quantity="1" />            
          </ColorMap>
      </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
      <Name>demostyle_default</Name>
      <ogc:Filter>
        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          <ogc:Function name="language"/>
          <ogc:Literal/>
        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
      </ogc:Filter>
      <RasterSymbolizer>
          <ColorMap  type="values">
            <ColorMapEntry label="Default" color="#006100" quantity="1" />
          </ColorMap>
      </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: language isn't a supported parameter in the SLD specification for GetLegendGraphic